# tidyr enframe vs pivot_longer for named vector

Tags: r, tidyr

For converting a named vector to a 2-column tibble, it seems like `pivot_longer()` should work the same as `enframe()` but it doesn't.

```
names <- c("John", "Steve", "Jim", "Christopher")
name_chars <- sapply(names, nchar)

name_chars_enf <- enframe(name_chars, name = "Name", value = "Chars")

  # A tibble: 4 x 2
  Name        Chars
  <chr>       <int>
1 John            4
2 Steve           5
3 Jim             3
4 Christopher    11

name_chars_piv_long <- pivot_longer(name_chars, names_to = "Name", values_to = "Chars")

Error in is_call(expr, paren_sym) : 
  argument "expr" is missing, with no default
```

Why doesn't `pivot_longer()` work this way?

Comment: If you look at `data` parameter in `pivot_longer()`, it says `A data frame to pivot`.

Comment: Oversight on my part.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @tmfmnk, you need to transform your vector into a dataframe using `pivot_longer`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
t <- data.frame(rbind(name_chars))
t %>% pivot_longer(everything(),names_to = "Names",values_to = "Chars")

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Names       Chars
  <chr>       <int>
1 John            4
2 Steve           5
3 Jim             3
4 Christopher    11
```

**Alternative (provided by @akrun)**

You can do it into a single line using:

```r
name_chars %>% as.list %>% as_tibble() %>% pivot_longer(everything())
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out, beyond the data.frame issue, that the error was being thrown because I wasn't including `everything()` as the second arg in `pivot_longer()`.

Comment: I went through this error whn trying to reproduce your example. That's why I posted my answer

Comment: Or use `name_chars %>% as.list %>% as_tibble %>% pivot_longer(everything())`

Comment: @akrun, yes that's work too. Thanks. I will add it to my answer